# Rails sending Email with Postmark with message stream configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer, postmark

I am sending some email messages using the Postmark API with the postmark gem.

```
gem 'postmark-rails'
```

I want the messages to use a specific Message Stream. I am trying to do it using the action mailer default_options hash.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :postmark

config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = {
  api_token: "API_TOKEN"
}

config.action_mailer.default_options = {
  MessageStream: "MY-STREAM"
}
```

If i use this configuration it works on development enviroment. But if i set the exact same code in production env it will not work, sending my mail to the default stream.

How can I configure it and why they behave different?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally use certain streamid inside ActionMailer, I was able to do it by setting the header.

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def some_mail
    headers["MESSAGE-STREAM"] = "broadcast"
    mail(...)
  end
end
```

Sadly this is not documented in either `postmark-rails` or `postmark` gems.